# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php

I have notice I started getting this error message in my error log:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php
/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/pdf.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions
/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/pdf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file
 or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

The error goes into the log every time you open the main page but everything seems to be working. Does anyone have any ideas what might cause this error to occur, I have been change the code in the past few days but when read back though I can't find anything that could be the cause.

there's nothing on the page that I have changed for when it initially loads but i have changed things in areas where I have if (isset...etc.

Any possible suggestions are appreciated. what type of command might this error message be caused by?

Comment: does that extension exist?

Comment: not one that i've put on there at all or that i'm requeesting at anypoint to my knowledge

Comment: pdf.so is no where in my code

Comment: If you need the PDF extension functional, I would reinstall PHP.  `sudo apt-get purge php5`  --  `sudo apt-get install php5`  --  This **WILL** revert PHP to original php.ini/extensions, so any extensions you have, you'll need to reinstall as well.    If you DON'T need the PDF extension, follow @Alexander's answer to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your PHP installation is configured to load http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdf.php and cannot find it.

Remove its respective extension entry in php.ini or fix the path or ensure the file exists if you require it.

Comment: well... what if he wanted or is using the pdf extension?

Comment: ha. maybe i missed the last part of that response?

Comment: Will do Thanks Alexander. Much appreciated